# Angular 8: Why UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@8.0.0?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I upgraded to the latest Angular 8 version, and the update went fine. It is now working as before the update.

I just see weird messages when doing `npm list` (after `npm install` finishes):

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@8.0.0
...
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@8.0.0
...
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@8.0.0
```

Why is it the case?

I guess the packages are not missing since the app works well and they are in my `package.json` file:

```
"@angular/common": "8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/core": "8.0.0",
```

I have the latest `node` and `npm`:

```
npm -v
6.9.0
node -v
v12.3.1
```

**Edit 2**:
`npm ls` output is: [Git gist](https://gist.github.com/MicMicMon/99148cc98900c72b606b5dff4a963c6c)

**Edit**:
package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^12.3.1",
    "npm": "^6.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --optimization",
    "compodoc": "compodoc --tsconfig compodoc-config.ts --output ./doc --theme material --name 'API documentation'"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^11.1.0",
    "acorn": "^6.1.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.0.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "d3": "^5.9.2",
    "d3-sankey": "^0.12.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "force-ssl-heroku": "^1.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.2.1",
    "ngx-logger": "^3.3.11",
    "ngx-webstorage-service": "^4.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/d3-sankey": "^0.11.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "tslint": "~5.12.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this in the heroku build log too.

Comment: Provide the full output or your package.json

Comment: ok thanks, added full packages.json

Comment: Could you also add the full console output?

Comment: Thanks, added as a gist. You can see errors on not-updated packages, but I don't think it should lead to UNMET on the installed versions anyway?

Comment: I tried removing node_modules & package-lock of course, but it doesn't solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0, required by ngx-logger@3.3.13
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0, required by codelyzer@4.5.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@>=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0, required by codelyzer@4.5.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0, required by ng-recaptcha@4.2.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0, required by ngx-logger@3.3.13
```

The output states that some of your 3rd party packages require lower versions of some of the angular packages (< 8.0.0).

**You have to either:**

- Upgrade the version of those 3rd party packages to one compatible with angular@8.0.0
- Downgrade your angular version to one compatible with the 3rd party requirements
- Ignore the errors, assuming that the changes introduced between the mayor versions of angular dont break the 3rd party packages

Comment: ah ok, so you mean `npm` actually says `version 8.0.0 is installed, but UNMET dep on version < 8`. Makes sense, the message is a bit misleading